# Is possible put React JS on Sharepoint Extension?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, react, reactjs

I am new to SharePoint development, and in need to create a custom side panel (with React), when click on item of list view.

Is it possible to use React JS while developing SPFx extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer to your question is **Yes**.

Even if it does not give you an option to choose the JavaScript framework while creating package, you can always install the dependencies and use React JS/Knockout or any other JavaScript framework for development of SPFx extensions.

**References**:

1. [SPFx Extensions Samples](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples).
2. [SPFx List View Command Set Example using React JS (react-command-directions)](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-extensions/tree/master/samples/react-command-directions).
3. [Overview of SharePoint Framework Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).
4. [Using React Components In SPFx Extension Application Customizer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-react-components-in-spfx-extension-application-customizer/).

Comment: Thanks! I already resolve the problem, i have tryed create the project with current version of yeoman, and in this version yeoman put a old version of gulp in the project. When a import react 16 this old version of this gulp request react in a wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem.  When I tried to create the project with the current version of yeoman and in this version yeoman put an old version of gulp in the project.  When he tried to import react 16, the old version of this gulp requested react in the wrong way.  I solved this issue by developing my project into an existing spfx sample project available on spfx github